# Focus state in Jetpack's Compose Previews

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to generate previews for different states of my component, which is based on Material `TextField`. In order to do snapshot tests with [Showkase](https://github.com/airbnb/Showkase) and [Paparazzi](https://cashapp.github.io/paparazzi/), I want to create a preview where my text field is focused, hence rendering the different outline in a different color. Is there a way I can achieve the desired result?

I tried different things such a using a focusRequester, but none work at while rendering preview. The only way I can get it to work is by starting the interactive preview, but that would not work with paparazzi.

```
@Preview
@Composable
internal fun TextFieldPreview(
    @PreviewParameter(TextFieldPreviewParameterProvider::class) 
    parameter: TextFieldPreviewParameter
) {
    with(parameter) {
        val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

        MyTextField(
            value = "Text",
            onValueChange = {},
            isEnabled = isEnabled,
            isPrefilled = isPrefilled,
            isError = isError,
            errorMessage = isError.runIfTrue { "Error message" },
            modifier = Modifier.focusRequester(focusRequester)
        )

        LaunchedEffect(isFocused) {
            if (isFocused){
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
        }
    }
}

internal data class TextFieldPreviewParameter(
    val isFocused: Boolean,
    val isEnabled: Boolean,
    val isPrefilled: Boolean,
    val isError: Boolean,
)
```

Comment: Could you post the `MyTextField` composable?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work on the previews but it does work on the last version of Paparazzi:

```kotlin
Component(
    // more values...
    interactionSource = object : DefaultMutableInteractionSource {
        override val interactions = flowOf(HoverInteraction.Enter())
    },
)
```

Where `Component`should be something like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
public fun Component(
    // more arguments...
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
) {
    // code that uses interactionSource to know if the component is hovered or not
}
```